# Git over Email?

Tags: git, version-control

Assuming network access is sporadic with no central server, what would be the best way to use git to keep three or more branches in sync? Is there a way to extract just my deltas, email those, and merge them on the other end?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While "git format-patch" and "git am" are great ways to manage patches from non-git sources, for git repositories you should investigate "git bundle".

"git bundle" and the subcommands "create" and "unbundle" can be used to create and use a binary blob of incremental commits that can be used to transfer branch history across a 'weak' link via an alternative file transfer mechanism (e.g. email, snail-mail, etc.).

git bundles will preserve commit ids, whereas format-patch/am will not resulting in the destination commits not being identical (different SHA1s).

Comment: Nice.  I've heard of the patch based handlers before (see other posts) but git-bundle is something I really need.  http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html

Answer (score 5):

See the main pages for [`git-format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and [`git-am`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html). This is one of the ways the system was originally designed to work with.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tools in git to use to mail patches or import mailed patches: **git-am** (apply patches from a mailbox), **git-format-patch** (prepare email for mailing), **git-send-email** (send a collection of patches via mail), etc. man 1 git has a complete list.