# How can developers use Git with no shared network access?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git over Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85051/git-over-email)

I'm new to Git and am interested in using it on Windows. I wish to write a program with one other developer, but we have no access to a shared machine on a network.

The only way we can really communicate data is via e-mail and physically bringing flash drives over from time to time.

What is the best way for each of us to pass to each other our changes so we can update our own repositories w/ the others changes?

Is this a scenario where you would use patches or the local protocol?

If possible could an example of the commands necessary to export and import the changes be given?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Git is built for e-mail patch exchanges communication!

Comment: 3-rd party repo and pull/push?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways:

- Git has a [git-bundle](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-bundle.html) command, that allows packing up what you need to push, so you can send it over email.
- Or you can have the "central" repo on a USB key and sync to it alternately.

I would rather not recommend the `git-formath-patch`/`git-am` approach, because that does not transfer history, so you'd end up with different repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [git-format-patch](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-format-patch.html) and [git-am](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-am.html) these are the commands to create patches, share them by e-mail and apply them to a repo.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub have just released a client for Windows. I'm presuming you both have internet access?

http://windows.github.com/