# Working around an unresponsive Git server (can't do git pull origin) with patches

Tags: git, email

Our central Git server is down at the moment, and my working copy is out of date, I'm working from home today, and I'm trying to see if there's a way that I can get a colleague who has the latest history to email me equivalent data to a `git pull origin master`.

For the sake of argument, let's call the latest commit I have in my working copy of the `master` branch `abcd1234`. My colleague's working copy is up to date with the server, and latest commit in his working copy of the master branch is `ef123456`.

How can he email me a dataset that covers the history from `abcd1234` to `ef123456`, and how can I apply it to my working copy? (And is this equivalent to a pull from the server? Or would I be getting myself into tricky territory?)

I tried looking at [git-format-patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) but it doesn't seem to have any examples of this type, and I'm paranoid about getting the syntax right -- if I don't have high confidence that I know what I'm doing, then I'll wait for the server to be back up, which might take a few days.

---

Hmm. [Another stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85051/git-over-email) mentioned that [git-bundle](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) is more appropriate. But I'm still not sure how to capture history of a branch from one rev-hash to another.

Comment: The disadvantage of `git format-patch` is that you'll get different SHAs. Not a big deal if you always rebase anyway.

Comment: If you have a true VLAN, it's trivial to clone a git directory over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

If—this is a very big *if*—everything is smoothly linear and you are the right committer and some other things line up, it is possible to use `git format-patch` and `git am` to transfer these commits and even keep their original hash IDs.  But you're much better off with `git bundle`, which essentially breaks `git fetch` into its constituent parts.

The Git documentation is pretty obscure.  See instead [How to use git-bundle for keeping development in sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3635952/1256452)  Use something that encodes the bundle data into a form suitable for transporting from computer A to computer B (scp, turn into emailed binary, or whatever it takes).  Then just `git fetch` from the bundled data once it's on the target computer.